# Eclipse RCP "About Window"

Tags: eclipse-rcp

While developing "about window" in eclipse RCP, we need to define:

```
 aboutText=My text which will be shown in about window
```

in about.ini file.

I need to add version number, which is defined in the overview page 
of the .product file.
Is there any way to parametrize this string?

I have tried to add {featureVersion} to aboutText, but it doesn't work - my about window is not displayed then.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so difficult... Use `{0}`, `{1}`, etc in the text itself and construct a file `about.mappings` with:

```
0=abc
1=def
...
```

Now the problem is reduced to making substitutions in the mappings file. Unfortunately there are no standardized way to do this in Eclipse. For Tycho, I typically use maven filters as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

Comment: Is there any way to get version automatically? Like described here: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/m92252023.html ? The {featureVersion} tag is not working for me.

Comment: As far as I know, this feature is only available when you brand features, not when you brand products. See http://book.javanb.com/eclipse-rich-client-platform-designing-coding-and-packaging-java-applications-oct-2005/ch14lev1sec4.html